# iOS application ID changes

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework

I'm testing around with iOS. In my simulator I saw this problem coming up:

I take a picture & write the file uri to a file.
This is the link to my image written in the file:

> file:///Users/thomasvanommeslaeger/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5EBF6158-9183-482E-89D5-7A93EC149D8B/data/Containers/Data/Application/D3C85587-BA89-47F9-AD57-5629FF85A759/Library/Files/Projects/awd/2015-02-16/0.jpg

When I re-run my application, the app id changes & the application can't find the image.
New path to image:

> file:///Users/thomasvanommeslaeger/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5EBF6158-9183-482E-89D5-7A93EC149D8B/data/Containers/Data/Application/80D7EAD1-7249-400A-80E1-51362D5ED288/Library/Files/Projects/awd/2015-02-16/0.jpg

Does anybody know how to fix this or what the main problem is?
The app is written with Ionic cordova.
Thx!

Answer (score 2):

How are you obtaining these file paths?  You should never use absolute paths in your app as they will change (as you have found out).  You should use [`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains) to obtain the path to the appropriate directory at run-time.

For example, you can get the path to the documents directory using

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Wrote it in cordova so I use cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory. (you can find it on https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md ) 
So I'll have to use relative paths & paste the return of cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory before it :)